# linechart with getTimeChartView achrtengine

Tags: android, achartengine

I have used  Achartengine for date VS value chart

I have dynamic y axis values of 154.31 and 175 and x axis value of dates with 02/10  and 
02/12 but it not correctly showing in map here is image,the y values are showing correctly

[image: Chart us Not correctly showing date values]

I have using following settings of chart in code,here is function of code that i call from my activity

```
public LinearLayout execute(Context context, List<Date[]> dates, List<double[]> values, int[] colors, String max, String title, String tag) {
    String[] titles = new String[] { tag };

    Log.d("size", "dates Size" + dates.get(0).length);
    Log.d("size", "Vsalues Size" + values.get(0).length);

    // int[] colors = new int[] { Color.BLUE};
    PointStyle[] styles = new PointStyle[] { PointStyle.POINT };
    XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer = buildRenderer(colors, styles);
    setChartSettings(renderer, title, "Date", tag, dates.get(0)[0].getTime(), dates.get(0)[dates.get(0).length - 1].getTime(), 0,
            Double.parseDouble(max), Color.GRAY, Color.LTGRAY);
    if (values.get(0).length > 5) {
        renderer.setXLabels(4);
        renderer.setYLabels(5);

    } else {
        renderer.setXLabels(values.get(0).length);
        renderer.setYLabels(values.get(0).length + 1);

    }
    renderer.setShowGrid(true);
    renderer.setXLabelsAlign(Align.RIGHT);
    renderer.setYLabelsAlign(Align.RIGHT);
    renderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(false);
    renderer.getSeriesRendererCount();
    int length = renderer.getSeriesRendererCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        SimpleSeriesRenderer seriesRenderer = renderer.getSeriesRendererAt(0);
        seriesRenderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);

    }
    GraphicalView gview = null;
    gview = ChartFactory.getTimeChartView(context, buildDateDataset(titles, dates, values), renderer, "MM/dd");

    LinearLayout lnr = null;
    lnr = new LinearLayout(context);
    lnr.addView(gview);
    return lnr;

}
```

Please give me some suggestion
Thanks in advance

Comment: Hello bindalbhai.. Mansi here.. How r u? R u der?

Answer (score 0):

I used

```
renderer.setXRoundedLabels(false) // Version 1.1.0
```

worked!